# Dealing with twip precision limit placed on DisplayObject positioning

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a project to render xps content in flash, and am running into the twip (1/20 of a unit) precision limit in flash. The twip limit is mentioned in the swf file format, but in the flash as3 documentation it's only mentioned in PrintJob.addPage method. However, when setting the DisplayObject x and y properties, any precision less than 0.05 is rounded. Regardless of any scaling. The code below demonstrates this issue.

```
    package
    {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.GraphicsPathCommand;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    public class TWIPTest extends Sprite
    {
        // can change behaviour by switching between createPoint and drawPoint
        public function TWIPTest()
        {
            this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            // scale our unit square so we can see what is happening
            scaleX = 400; scaleY = 400;
            // draw grid
            var grid : Sprite = new Sprite();
            addChild(grid);
            grid.graphics.lineStyle(TWIP, 0x888888);
            drawGrid(1 / TWIP, 1 / TWIP, TWIP, TWIP, grid);
            // center of unit square
            var cx : Number = 0.5; 
            var cy : Number = 0.5;

            var shape : Shape;
            // GREEN in middle of unit square
            this.addChild(createPoint(cx, cy, 0x00FF00));
            //drawPoint(cx, cy, 0x00FF00, this.graphics);

            // BLUE one TWIP away from GREEN
            this.addChild(createPoint(cx + TWIP, cy + TWIP, 0x0000FF));
            //drawPoint(cx + TWIP, cy + TWIP, 0x0000FF, this.graphics);

            // RED half a TWIP away from GREEN (this does not work....) 
            this.addChild(createPoint(cx + (TWIP / 2), cy + (TWIP / 2), 0xFF0000, 0.5));
            //drawPoint(cx + (TWIP / 2), cy + (TWIP / 2), 0xFF0000, this.graphics, 0.5);

            // now insert new container to work around limit encontered with RED point
            var container : Sprite = new Sprite();
            this.addChild(container);
            container.scaleX = 0.5; container.scaleY = 0.5;
            container.addChild(createPoint(2 * cx + TWIP, 2 * cy + TWIP, 0xFF00FF, 1.0, 2 * TWIP));
            //drawPoint(cx + (TWIP / 2), cy + (TWIP / 2), 0xFF00FF, container.graphics);
        }
        static private function createPoint(x:Number, y:Number,color:uint,alpha:Number=1.0,radius:Number=0.05):Shape
        {
            var shape : Shape = new Shape();
            shape.x = x; shape.y = y;
            shape.graphics.beginFill(color,alpha);
            shape.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
            shape.graphics.endFill();
            return shape;
        }
        static private function drawPoint(x:Number, y:Number,color:uint,target:Graphics,alpha:Number=1.0,radius:Number=0.05):void
        {
            target.beginFill(color,alpha);
            target.drawCircle(x, y, radius);
            target.endFill();
        }
        // drawGrid from @Feltope
        private function drawGrid(numColumns:Number, numRows:Number, cellHeight:Number, cellWidth:Number, grid:Sprite):void 
        {
            for (var col:Number = 0; col < numColumns + 1; col++)
            {
                for (var row:Number = 0; row < numRows + 1; row++)
                {
                    grid.graphics.moveTo(col * cellWidth, 0);
                    grid.graphics.lineTo(col * cellWidth, cellHeight * numRows);
                    grid.graphics.moveTo(0, row * cellHeight);
                    grid.graphics.lineTo(cellWidth * numColumns, row * cellHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        static private const TWIP : Number = 0.05;
    }
    }
```

This [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780295/matrix-transforms-on-adjacent-sprites-causing-subpixel-gaps) also mentions this issue.

The problem is that in parsing xps files this can happen anytime, and many times, for example

```
<Canvas RenderTransform="96.201126,0,0,-95.787476,713.62598,207.05859">
<Path Data="..." RenderTransform="0.010394889,0,0,-0.010439778,-7.4180626,2.1616458">
```

Notice the dx in the Path element, which seems trivial, but the parent Canvas (and other parents above this) scale it up so the rounding of dx to 0 or 0.05 is very noticeable.

I could add Sprite containers whenever this happens, as in the code above, but that's going to bloat memory and slow down rendering.

My question (finally), has anyone dealt with this issue? Any ideas on a better way of handling this limit? Workarounds? Any help appreciated. cheers

Answer (score 0):

what is the biggest problem here? How it looks on screen or that after parsing the precision is lost? You can't do with rendering but you could do modified DisplayObject that will store for example position then reading it will contain the precision kept. or am I missing the point?:)

**Edit:**
Following is an example of custom display objects (Shape and Sprite)

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
internal class MySprite extends Sprite
{
    protected var m_nX:Number;
    protected var m_nY:Number;


    override public function get x():Number 
    {
        return m_nX;
    }

    override public function set x(value:Number):void 
    {
        m_nX = value;
        super.x = m_nX;
    }
    override public function get y():Number 
    {
        return m_nY;
    }

    override public function set y(value:Number):void 
    {
        m_nY = value;
        super.y = m_nY;
    }
}
internal class MyShape extends Shape
{
    protected var m_nX:Number;
    protected var m_nY:Number;


    override public function get x():Number 
    {
        return m_nX;
    }

    override public function set x(value:Number):void 
    {
        m_nX = value;
        super.x = m_nX;
    }
    override public function get y():Number 
    {
        return m_nY;
    }

    override public function set y(value:Number):void 
    {
        m_nY = value;
        super.y = m_nY;
    }
}
```

Add this to your example and replace any instantiation of Shape and use MyShape, same for Sprite, replace it by MySprite. There will be no visual difference but the x and y of them will return precise values.

This is a sample test for precision keeping:

```
addChild(createPoint(0.51000005, 0.510000049, 0x800000, 1, TWIP));
var disp :DisplayObject = getChildAt(numChildren - 1);
trace(disp.x, disp.y);
```

will trace 0.51000005, 0.510000049 but above test added to your example without MySprite and MyShape custom DisplayObjects will return 0.5 0.5.

Comment: The biggest problem is I can't make the flash output look like the xps source :( Currently I add the Path element as a Shape to the Canvas Sprite element. I could 'flatten' by concat the matrices and drawing the path directly on the sprite, or go all the way to the display list root and apply all the matrices. But both cases only work in trivial situations, and break a bunch of other situations that require clipping/opacity masks/etc. Finally, storing the param doesn't help since, the x/y props of DisplayObject enforce the 0.05 precision limit whenever they're modified.

Comment: I've modified my answer and your example - check if it helps you at all, the DisplayObject will change but I said to create custom version of Sprite or Shape that will internally store precise x/y values.